# Celsius and Fahrenheit Converter

Tags: c, converting

I'm very new to programming in C and I attempted to make a program that converts temperatures to and from Fahrenheit and Celsius. I have been running the program and I have realized that not all conversions are correct. For example, if I use the boiling point of water (100C or 212F), I get an incorrect answer. I thought that I used the correct formulas. I was wondering if you wouldn't mind reviewing this quick program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    float c;
    float f;
    int w;

    printf("Type 1 if you would like to convert to Farenheit\n");
    printf("Type 2 if you would like to convert to Celcius\n");

    scanf("%i", &w);


// Loop to make sure value is 1 or 2

    while(w != 1 && w !=2) {

        fprintf(stderr, "You didn't input a valid number. Please Try Again\n");
        scanf("%i", &w);    
    }

// Celsius --> Fahrenheit
    if(w == 1){
        printf("Input the Celcius Temperature\n");
        scanf("%f", &c);
        printf("You entered %f\n", c);
        f = c * (9./5.) + 32.;
        printf("%f in Fareheit is %f\n", c, f);
     }

// Fahrenheit --> Celsius
    if(w == 2){
        printf("Input the Farenheit Temperature\n");
        scanf("%f", &f);
        printf("You entered %f\n",f);
        c = (f - 32.) * (5./9.);
        printf("%f in Celcius is %f\n", f, c);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably the integer division in `9/5` and `5/9`. The result is 1 and 0, respectively, due to truncation to integer. Use `9./5` and `5./9`, respectively.

Comment: Please update this in the posted code, otherwise it's technically "broken", and broken code is off-topic here: the code to review must fully work as intended

Answer (score 3):

1. Spelling ["Celsius"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius) (3 places)

   ```
   printf("Type 2 if you would like to convert to Celcius\n");
   ```
2. Better to get return value of input functions (4 places).  Even in learner code, it saves time during debug

   ```
   // scanf("%i", &w)
   int ret = scanf("%i", &w);
   assert(ret == 1);
   ```
3. Infinite loop should user enter non-numeric input as the offending input is not consumed.

   ```
   while(w != 1 && w !=2) {
     fprintf(stderr, "You didn't input a valid number. Please Try Again\n");
     // scanf("%i", &w);    
     ret = scanf("%i", &w);    
     assert(ret == 1);
   }
   ```
4. Style: Suggest `.0`.  Also since the input and output are `float`, code could use `float` constants.  In general, unless floating point math is intensive or has larges array of data, recommend using `double` as that is C's default FP type.

   ```
   // f = c * (9./5.) + 32.;
   f = c * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
   f = c * (9.0f/5.0f) + 32.0f;
   ```
5. Functional simplification: Rather than enter a number to indicate the desired temperature scale, enter `'C'` or `'F'`.

   ```
   char scale;
   char scale_new;
   ret = scanf("%f %c", &temperature, &scale);
   assert(ret == 2);

   switch (scale) {
     case 'C':
     case 'c': 
       temperature_new = temperature*9/5 + 32;  // math is all FP
       scale_new = 'F'; 
       break;
     case 'F':
     case 'f': 
       temperature_new = (temperature - 32)*5/9;  // math is all FP
       scale_new = 'C'; 
       break;
     default:
       // Handle bad scale
   }
   printf("... converts to %f %c\n", temperature_new, scale_new);
   ```